# What's the difference between "or" and | in ruby?

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

I thought the only difference was between `|` and `||` where `|` would be equivalent to `or`. But I realised the latter is incorrect and now I'm confused.

**AMEND**: I understand this question to be different from [ruby bitwise or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384571/ruby-bitwise-or) while mine is about the lack of understanding of the difference between bitwise and boolean operators as pointed out here in comments and answers.
Besides, in my opinion the answers to this question have been more relevant and clearer to the problem itself. Flagging as duplicate would dissuade users from the better answers.

Comment: In ruby, `|` is a bitwise operator, which is different than the boolean operator `||`. If you don't know what bitwise operators are, this looks like a decent source for an introduction: https://www.calleerlandsson.com/rubys-bitwise-operators/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ruby bitwise or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384571/ruby-bitwise-or)

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm . Additionally these have different precedence levels https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html . `or` and `||` are both Logical Operators although due to its precedence level `or` is usually referred to as a control flow operator. `|` is a bit bitwise operator to perform a bit by bit compilation e.g. `60 | 13 #=> 61` because in binary it would be `111100 | 1101` which equates to `111101` or `61` because the first 4 ones are present in 60 and the last one is present in 13

Comment: Thanks for the sources. They are helpful.

Comment: This is not a proper duplicate of the nominated exemplar.  Even if it were, I wouldn't vote to close, since this is a better asked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|` operator is a *binary mathematical* operator, that is it does a binary OR and works on a numerical level:

```
1 | 2
# => 3
4 | 3
# => 7
1 | 2 | 3
# => 3
```

This is because it's manipulating individual values as if they were binary:

```
0b01 | 0b10
# => 3 (0b11)
```

The `||` operator is a *logical* one, that is it returns the first value that's logically true. In Ruby only literal `nil` and `false` values evaluates as logically false, everything else, including `0`, empty strings and arrays, is true.

So:

```
1 || 2
# => 1
0 || 1
# => 0
```

The `or` operator works almost exactly the same as `||` except it's at a much lower precedence. That means other operators are evaluated first which can lead to some problems if you're not anticipating this:

```
a = false || true
# => true
a
# => true

a = false or true
# => true
a
# => false
```

This is because it's actually interpreted as:

```
(a = false) or true
```

This is because `=` has a [higher precedence](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) when being evaluated.

Comment: "The `|` operator is a *binary* operator" – Well, so is `||`. In fact, apart from `~`, `!`, `-@`, and `+@`, which are unary, and `?:`, which is ternary, *all* operators in Ruby are binary.

Comment: True, they're binary as in take two components. I'll clarify the phrasing as context is important here.

Answer (score 1):

`||` and `or` are special built-in operators. Which means they could (and indeed *do*) have behavior that cannot be expressed in Ruby. In particular, `||` and `or` are non-strict and lazy in their right operand, whereas Ruby is actually a strict and eager language.

OTOH, `|` is just a method call like any other method call. There is absolutely nothing special about it. Which means:

- it is strict
- it is eager
- any object can choose to respond to it however it wants

Whereas `||` and `or` are language built-in operators, which are

- non-strict in their right operand
- lazy in their right operand
- their behavior is hard-coded and independent of any particular object, it is always the same and cannot be changed

The only difference between `||` and `or` is precedence: `or` has very low precedence (and it has the same precedence as `and`).